# php pop-up update form - close window and refresh parent page

Tags: php, forms

I have a PHP Pop-Up form that updates a record in the database.  I have added code That I found in the forum to close the window when the update button is clicked.  Works fine in FireFox and IE but does not work when using Chrome.  Any ideas on how I can fix this?

I would also like to have the parent page update/refresh when the pop-up window closes to sow the changes made by the pop-up form.  I have no idea to go about this.

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
function closeSelf(){
   document.forms['form1'].submit();
   window.close();
}
</script> 


<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
  <table align="center" class="BulletList">
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Weight:</td>
      <td align="center"><input type="text" name="icmWeight" value="<?php echo $row_SKUUpdateDIMs['icmWeight']; ?>" size="5" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Length:</td>
      <td align="center"><input type="text" name="icmLength" value="<?php echo $row_SKUUpdateDIMs['icmLength']; ?>" size="5" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="baseline">
       <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
       <td><input type="button" value="Update record" onclick="closeSelf();" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
       <p>
       <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1" />
       <input type="hidden" name="icmKEY" value="<?php echo $row_SKUUpdateDIMs['icmKEY']; ?>" />
        </p>
</form>
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to close a window that's still submitting a form. You should wait for the form submission to complete before closing it.

Comment: @Jack - So would you suggest an update button that submits the form and a second button to close the window?

Answer (score 1):

You should either:

1. Wait for the form to submit. The server side can generate a small piece of JavaScript that can then close the window.
2. Use jQuery (or others) to serialize the form data and pass it to the parent for submission; this would allow you to immediately close the window while the form is being processed.

To let a parent window do anything from the popup (assuming they're in the same domain), you can reference the parent using `opener`.

**Example**

Let's assume the parent window defined a function `helloWorld()`; from the popup you can call it like `opener.helloWorld()`.

Comment: So what is the code I would put on the parent page and what is the code I would put in the pop-up window?  I am a novice.

Comment: @Rick3rd then do option #1 :)

Comment: Any thoughts as to why my code above does not work in Chrome but does work in IE and Firefox?

Comment: @Rick3rd probably in Chrome, it cancels the submission when the window gets closed.